# Yii2 pjax pagination not working well in modal pop up

Tags: pagination, yii2, pjax, modalpopup

I stuck in the condition where I clicked on the modal pop-up's grid view pagination link, modal pop up gets closed and shows further records in browser tab.

I got the answer by adding renderAjax($viewPath) instead of renderPartial($viewPath). It works for me but now when I click on pagination, first time works but second time it doesn't work. I saw in console.ajax call is making but response not showing in modal popup.

Comment: show us your code please

Answer (score 0):

You should put the pagination code outside the Pjax.

```
<?php Pjax::begin() ?>
// code here
<?php Pjax::end() ?>


<?php echo \yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pages,
    'options' => ['class' => 'pagination']
]); ?>
```

Hope that helps.